# Comparing a pointer with integer

Tags: c

I am making a binary search tree program and I want to traverse to the node whose left or right child is to be selected for inserting the element. Whereas in the while condition I am getting warning of comparison of pointer with integer. Help me

```
 while(temp1->data != NULL)
   {
       temp2=temp1;
       if(value<=temp1->data)
       {
           temp1=temp1->lchild;
       }
       else
       {
           temp1=temp1->rchild;
       }
   }
```

Comment: _Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example._

Comment: We need to see the relevant declarations, preferably in the form or a [mcve], as well as the exact error message.

Comment: Is `temp1->data` an integer? Then it should not be compared to `NULL` since `NULL` is a pointer. If you want to compare the integer with zero then compare it with zero. Something that is not a pointer can never be a null pointer.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude It is NULL that is integer, because NULL is 0. He should use nullptr.

Comment: @qqqqq In C `NULL` is often defined as `((void *) 0)`, but it can be anything that the platform think is a null pointer (including plain `0`). It's also a semantic thing, a null pointer is not the same as the integer zero. Lastly, `nullptr` doesn't exist in C.

Answer (score 0):

Your `while` loop test is wrong. It should be testing for a null pointer to a node, like this:

```
while(temp1 != NULL)  // <-- this line was wrong
{
    temp2=temp1;
    if(value<=temp1->data)
    {
        temp1=temp1->lchild;
    }
    else
    {
        temp1=temp1->rchild;
    }
}
```